# How to remove renderflex error while using keyboard in FAB in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a Keyboard in my Floating Action Button in Flutter. It is causing a RenderFlex Overflow Error. How Can I avoid it?

I tried using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` and also wrapped my contents into `SingleChildScrollView`, but it didn't worked.

Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff5f5f5),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: change==true ? 100 : 80,
          width: ScreenSize.screenWidth*0.95,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: context.screenWidth * 0.75,
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _txtController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          // labelText: "Activity Description*",
                          alignLabelWithHint: true,
                          label: Text(
                            "Type a message*",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: const Color(0xFF1C1B1F).withOpacity(.74),
                            ),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return "Please enter a message";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: context.screenWidth * 0.04,
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      debugPrint("Saved Id: ${userP!.erp!}, sent id: ${widget.data.result!.user!.username} and name is: ${widget.data.result?.user?.name}");
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          change=false;
                        });
                        final WhatAppMsgModel data = WhatAppMsgModel(
                          message: _txtController.text,
                          sentAt: DateTime.now(),
                          sentBy: userP.erp,
                          erpId: widget.data.result?.user?.username,
                          teacherErp: userP.erp,
                          activityId: widget.data.result!.activity!.toString(),
                          contact: widget.data.result!.user!.contactNo!,
                          isReply: false,
                        );

                        bool isDone = await ActivityServices().sendWhatsAppMessages(
                          data: data,
                          isClasswise: widget.data.isClasswise!,
                        );
                        if (isDone) {
                          debugPrint("Yes, sent");
                          chatP.addMessage(data);
                          _txtController.clear();
                          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                        } else {
                          debugPrint("Nope");
                          if (context.mounted) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                              content: Text("Something went wrong"),
                            ));
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      else {
                        setState(() {
                          change=true;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                      size: 36,
                    )).centered()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          title: const Text('Conversation'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 8.0,
              ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Consumer<MainProvider>(
                    builder: (context, value, child) => isLoading ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()): ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: value.chats.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          debugPrint("${value.chats[index].erpId} == ${userP!.erp!}");
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              BubbleSpecialThree(
                                text: value.chats[index].message!,
                                color: const Color(0xFF1B97F3),
                                tail: true,
                                isSender: value.chats[index].sentBy == userP.erp!
                                    ? true
                                    : false,
                                sent: value.chats[index].isReply==null ? true : !(value.chats[index].isReply!),
                                seen: value.chats[index].readAt==null || value.chats[index].readAt=='' ? false : true,
                                delivered: true,
                                key: ValueKey(value.chats[index]),
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ).py8();
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
   slivers: [
     SliverFillRemaining(
       hasScrollBody: false,
       child: Row(
         children: [],
       ),
     ),
   ],
  )
)
```

Comment: Nope, not working. See, my main Screen is scrollable, I only want  a way such that my textfield remain at bottom of my screen, which i can see anytime. I tried positioned, but it didn't worked.